# Want to redirect to a page

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect to the product page. This is my controller function.

```
public function RegisterBusiness(Request $request){

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {

        if(session()->has('user_id')){
            $request['mybiz_users_id']=Session()->get('user_id');
        }

        $this->businessTempService->insertRegisteredBusinessDetails($request);

        DB::commit();
        
        return $this->sendResponse('success', 'Registered Successfully, Thank You!', '', 200,route('web.registration.advanced-product-registration'));
        
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($ex);

        return $this->sendResponse('error', 'Something went wrong', '', 422);
    }
}
```

> But it is not working.

[It loads this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7r5y.png)

Comment: This is not an error, its a json response , if you redirect to product page then change `return $this->sendResponse('error', 'Something went wrong', '', 422);` to `return view('product.index');` or `return route('product');`

Comment: You can use `return redirect('web.registration.advanced-product-registration');` instead of `return $this->sendResponse('success', 'Registered Successfully, Thank You!', '', 200,route('web.registration.advanced-product-registration'));` or If you want to send welcome message to front-end return 200 and redirect using front-end

Comment: Do you come from products page to this controller function?

Comment: yeah. now it's working, Thank u @Ahmad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error, its a json response , if you redirect to product page then change

```
return $this->sendResponse('error', 'Something went wrong', '', 422);
```

to

```
return view('product.index');
```

or,  with name route :

```
return route('product');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\request()->expectsJson()` to find out whether you need a json response or not.

```
if (\request()->expectsJson()){
    return $this->sendResponse('success', 'Registered Successfully, Thank You!', '', 200,route('web.registration.advanced-product-registration'));
}else{
    return back();
}
```